# Android Xamarin application crashing when consuming Restful services in XML format

Tags: c#, android, web-services, rest, xamarin

I am trying to get data from a web service to my android application (via emulator). But it crashes **when trying to access the url.**

error goes here

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(@"http://localhost:20776/WebService1.asmx/GetLatestUsers");
```

[image: Error when accessing URL]

Comment: Stack trace would help, plus some text-based code.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots.  Google can't index a screenshot, and they're difficult to read.  Take the time to post the relevant portion of your code as text.  Second, when you get an Unhandled Exception dialog you can use the Break function to stop execution and examine the Exception object and get the details about what caused the exception.  Finally, you can't use "localhost" in this way, because it refers to your Android emulator/device, NOT the local machine the emulator is running on.